# Where can i find registry entry for SQL Server 2012 VSS Writer

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to check whether all default components installed during SQL Server Installation like VSS writer, Native client, Setup Support Files etc are present on the machine or not. I tried looking in `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and found entry for each component except the VSS writer.
So my question is : Where can I find the registry key for SQL Server 2012 VSS writer ? or is there any other way to detect it using C# & SQL/T-SQL?

Comment: would checking the services be enough? if its there and running (which is the default) you can assume its working.

Comment: I need something that returns true of false;Checking it manually is not the case;

Comment: the registry wont return a true/false by default either though, so I don't see the difference.  Your `if` is 'is VSSWriter service running = yes / no'

Comment: How do we find it then ?? Also VSS write may be stopped; So even in that case, the result that it exists should be positive;

Comment: Use `System.ServiceProcess` and `ServiceController` object, they do anything and everything with services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ServiceProcess` namespace and the `ServiceController` object you can find if VSS Writer exists on this machine (or any other you have access to).  Below is a very crude way of doing so:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace GetService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
            bool vssExists = false;
            foreach (ServiceController sc in services)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} is {1}", sc.DisplayName, sc.Status);

                if (sc.DisplayName.Equals("SQL Server VSS Writer"))
                    vssExists = true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(vssExists);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```